# How to get all the values and keys inside an array of objects separated with comma without inbuilt methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried to retrieve all the values of an plain object which returns an array separated with comma since I am using map().

```
var obj = { 1: 'Banana', 2: 'Orange'};
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e) {
 return obj[e]
})                           //returns ['Banana','Orange']
```

Where as I need all the values and keys as string separated by comma from below object array without using Object.values() and Object.keys

```
 input: var items = [{1:"Banana"}, {2:"Orange"}, {3:"Apple"}]
 output 1: "1,2,3" ---> keys
 output 2: "Banana,Orange,Apple" --> values
```

Problem is when the objects are inside an array I am not getting any idea how to retrieve keys and object values separately.

Kindly help!

Comment: please have a look here: [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: You can use for...of and for...in methods
You don't wanna use Object.values and Object.keys ?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have array of objects, i tried using that but I am getting objects while i iterate using for in

Comment: Downvoter kindly explain. my question was about array of objects without inbuilt types. if it persists show the duplication link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for ... in`

```js
const items = [{
  1: "Banana"
}, {
  2: "Orange"
}, {
  3: "Apple"
}];

let keys = '';
let values = '';

items.forEach((x) => {
  for (let y in x) {
    keys = `${keys}${keys.length ? ',' : ''}${y}`;
    values = `${values}${values.length ? ',' : ''}${x[y]}`;
  }
});

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

---

Using `Object.keys()` and `Array.reduce`

```js
const items = [{
  1: "Banana"
}, {
  2: "Orange"
}, {
  3: "Apple"
}];

const rets = items.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  Object.keys(x).forEach((y) => {
    tmp.keys = `${tmp.keys}${tmp.keys.length ? ',' : ''}${y}`;
    tmp.values = `${tmp.values}${tmp.values.length ? ',' : ''}${y}`;
  });

  return tmp;
}, {
  keys: [],
  values: [],
});

console.log(rets);
```

Comment: Objects are inside an array

Answer (score 2):

You can use array reduce & `join`
Inside reduce callback use `for..in` to iterate the object. `[[],[]]` is the accumulator & in the first array `keys` will be collected and in second array values will be collected.

Inside the `for..in` push the `keys` & `values` from each object.

Once done use `join` with delimiter `,` to create the string

```js
var items = [{
  1: "Banana"
}, {
  2: "Orange"
}, {
  3: "Apple"
}]
let vals = items.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    acc[0].push(keys);
    acc[1].push(curr[keys])
  }

  return acc;
}, [
  [],
  []
]);

console.log(vals[0].join(','), vals[1].join(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the array and in a nested for loop iterate over the object:

```js
var items = [{1:"Banana"}, {2:"Orange"}, {3:"Apple"}];

let keys = [];
let values = [];

for (let element of items){
    for (let i in element){
        keys.push(i);
        values.push(element[i]);
    }
}

keys = keys.join(",");
values = values.join(",");

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in) and [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...of) functions

```
const items = [{1:"Banana"}, {2:"Orange"}, {3:"Apple"}];
let keys = [];
let values = [];
for(let item of items){
  for(let key in item){
    keys.push(key);
    values.push(item[key]);
  }
}
// keys == [1, 2, 3]
// values == [Banana, Orange, Apple]
```

After this you can use the [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join) function

```
console.log(keys.join()); // Output : "1,2,3"
console.log(values.join()); // Output : "Orange,Banana,Apple"
```